# How to get the list of all the symbols exported by a library?

Tags: scheme, r6rs

Is there a method to get the list of all the method exported by a library?

Comment: Which Scheme are you using? Racket, Chicken, Guile, MIT, ???

Comment: @Aslan986: Which one? In IronScheme (and other psyntax based R6RS schemes) you can just call `environment-symbols`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable way to do this.  Different scheme implementations may provide an approach.